# Check for browser timeout while waiting for REST service response in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest, connection-timeout

I am calling a PUT REST service and if there occurs a timeout of 60 seconds on the browser side and not on the server side, then I have to display a popover.
How can I check for browser timeout in AngularJS?
(REST service response is not an error, it is just timing out on the browser side.)

```
cancelData: function(cancelData2) { //code
    return $http({ method: 'PUT', 
            data: cancelData2,
            url: endpointURL,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'something',
                      'Accept' : 'something'},
            timeout: 60000 });
}
```

Comment: show us what you've done so far

Comment: When user confirms he wants to delete the record, a loading icon is displayed to user and below cancelData function is called which calls the REST PUT service, now when there occurs a network connectivity issues or timeout of 60 seconds, then I need to display the popup.

Comment: cancelData: function(cancelData2) {
 //code
 return $http({
  method: 'PUT',
  data: cancelData2,
  url: endpointURL,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'something','Accept' : 'something'},
  timeout: 60000
 });
}

Comment: Add a `.catch` method to the chain to *catch* the timeout. See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage) and [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api).

Answer (score 1):

in angular config can set response time out to `$httpProvider` according to the error code.

if you want a global workaround for all http call then use this

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 6000;
}]);
```

Note that when the timeout is over response will enter in the error section of the promise, so you need to add the pop up over there.

if you want to set it to individual http request then use this approach

```
 $http.get("/home", { 
   timeout: 6000 
 })
   .success(success)
   .error(error);
```

Comment: Thanks. But, will there be an error code received if there were some network issues and timeout occurs because of that ?

Comment: See [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/)

Answer (score 0):

For angular $http, when the API timeouts, you get status -1 in error handling function of $http. But if you want to handle all the network error from a single handle, you could use angular `httpInterceptors`. Sample `httpInterceptors`:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('timeoutHttpIntercept');

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$rootScope', '$location',
        function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {
       return {
           'request': function (config) {
                return config;
           },
           'response': function (config) {
                return config;
           },
           'responseError': function (response) {
                return $q.reject(response);
           }
       };
    }]);
}])
```

The  `responseError`  receives all the $http errors. You can even mention custom timeouts here. Just define the timeoutHttpIntercept as a factory like this:

```
.factory('timeoutHttpIntercept', ['CONSTANTS', 'EMAIL_SERVER_URL', function (CONSTANTS, EMAIL_SERVER_URL) {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            config.timeout = 20000;
            return config;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
function timedHttp(delay) {
    var isTimeout = {value: false};
    var promise = $http.get('someUri').then(function(data){
        if(!isTimeout.value) {
          timerId.cancel();
            $scope.yourDataModal = data;
        }
    });
    var timerId = $timeout(function(){
        isTimeout.value = true;
        showTimeoutPopup();
    }, delay);
}
```